# CSS: Box flexible display

Tags: html, css

Can you help me do a css for this sample?

I want to display the card in 1 column when it's view on tablet devices,
and 2 column if it's view on desktop.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpivg.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your existing css attempts to achieve this? This will help other's to understand where you are right now to support you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Bootstrap's grid system here. I have attached a sample code with just two divs. This is for your better understanding. Before you proceed to cards, first play around with the grid system and make yourself wise in it. This is as simple as it looks. A bootstrap row is divided by equal 12 columns. They can be represented using- lg- large device, md- medium device, sm- small device and xs- extra small device.

`col-lg-6 col-md-12` -This implies that, the DOM elements should take 6 columns of a row when it is in Desktop view and 12 columns when it is in Tablet view.

Make sure you learn how media queries work, then proceed with bootstrap's grid system. Hope it helps!.. **Happy coding**.!!

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  #div1{
    background: #0ef;
  }
  #div2{
  background: #fe0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" id="div1">div 1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" id="div2">div 2</div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks you! this is also working, applied it on my project.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Grid system - bootstrap 4
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
<div class="media border border-secoundery m-2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSeLpmTC32CdJU5T9AuHFGCtPwbt_MCnhc4b7RPsm1uSK-0SslS" class="mr-3" style="max-width:100px" alt="...">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-2">test title 1</h5>
    content test
  </div>
</div> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
<div class="media border border-secoundery m-2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSeLpmTC32CdJU5T9AuHFGCtPwbt_MCnhc4b7RPsm1uSK-0SslS" class="mr-3" style="max-width:100px" alt="...">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-2">test title 1</h5>
    content test
  </div>
</div> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
<div class="media border border-secoundery m-2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSeLpmTC32CdJU5T9AuHFGCtPwbt_MCnhc4b7RPsm1uSK-0SslS" class="mr-3" style="max-width:100px" alt="...">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-2">test title 1</h5>
    content test
  </div>
</div> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
<div class="media border border-secoundery m-2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSeLpmTC32CdJU5T9AuHFGCtPwbt_MCnhc4b7RPsm1uSK-0SslS" class="mr-3" style="max-width:100px" alt="...">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-2">test title 1</h5>
    content test
  </div>
</div> 
 </div>
 
 
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty simple using css grid.

Let’s say you have 4 divs. Put those in a container. Set that container to:

```
container   {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

This sets 2 automatically scaled columns normally.
and then set a media query for your selected width of a tablet

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
container {
grid-template-columns: auto;
}
}
```

This means up to 500px, there will only be one column. No one else used css grid so I thought it would be cool to show.

I might have mixed up columns and rows cause I’m dumb but yea that’s it. I suggest you learn about media queries, and css grid/flexgrid/bootstrap